# Global buffer overflow analizando .text section en memoria

Tags: android, manejo-de-memoria, out-of-memory-error, overflow, native

Estoy implementando una aplicación de Android que en código nativo lee su propio código **cargado en memoria**. No me interesa leerlo en el disco, sino el que se esta ejecutando.

```
    extern char __ehdr_start;
    
    ElfW(Ehdr)* elfheader = (ElfW(Ehdr)*)&__ehdr_start;

    android_log("Self_textParser: ELF header [%1$p]", elfheader);

    ElfW(Phdr) *programHeader = (ElfW(Phdr)*)((uintptr_t)elfheader + elfheader->e_phoff);

    for (ElfW(Phdr)* current = programHeader; current < (programHeader + elfheader->e_phnum); ++current) {
        if (current->p_type != PT_LOAD) {
            android_log("Self_textParser: Discarding no loadable segment: p_offset (%1$p), p_vaddr (%2$p), p_paddr (%3$p), p_filesz (%4$p), p_memsz (%5$p), p_flags (%6$p)",
                 current->p_offset, current->p_vaddr, current->p_paddr, current->p_filesz, current->p_memsz, current->p_flags & 0xF);
            continue;
        }

        android_log("Self_textParser: Found a loadable segment: p_offset (%1$p), p_vaddr (%2$p), p_paddr (%3$p), p_filesz (%4$p), p_memsz (%5$p), p_flags (%6$p)",
             current->p_offset, current->p_vaddr, current->p_paddr, current->p_filesz, current->p_memsz, current->p_flags & 0xF);

        if ((current->p_flags & PF_X) != 0) {
            ElfW(Addr) loadBias = (uintptr_t)elfheader + current->p_vaddr;

            android_log("Self_textParser: loadBias: %1$p, len: %2$p", loadBias, current->p_memsz);

            unsigned char* p = loadBias;
            
            for (int j = 0; j + ALIGNMENT < current->p_memsz; j += ALIGNMENT, p += ALIGNMENT) {
                //android_log("Instruction: %02X%02X%02X%02X",*p,*(p+1),*(p+2),*(p+3));
                if (*(p + 3) == 0x04 && *(p + 2) == 0x03 && *(p + 1) == 0x02 && *p == 0x01) {
                    android_log("Instruction found");
                }
            }
```

El problema es que como veis en los logs aunque no llegue al máximo del tamaño del segmento se produce un global buffer overflow mucho antes...

```
2024-01-30 17:55:53.737 26800-26800 SampleApp   com.test.app.testsuite            D  Self_textParser: ELF header [0x6fad64a000]
2024-01-30 17:55:53.737 26800-26800 SampleApp   com.test.app.testsuite            D  Self_textParser: Discarding no loadable segment: p_offset (0x40), p_vaddr (0x40), p_paddr (0x40), p_filesz (0x1f8), p_memsz (0x1f8), p_flags (0x4)
2024-01-30 17:55:53.737 26800-26800 SampleApp   com.test.app.testsuite            D  Self_textParser: Found a loadable segment: p_offset (0x0), p_vaddr (0x0), p_paddr (0x0), p_filesz (0x25926d0), p_memsz (0x25926d0), p_flags (0x5)
2024-01-30 17:55:53.737 26800-26800 SampleApp   com.test.app.testsuite            D  Self_textParser: loadBias: 0x6fad64a000, len: 0x25926d0
2024-01-30 17:55:53.742 26794-26794 wrap.sh                 logwrapper                           I  =================================================================
2024-01-30 17:55:53.743 26794-26794 wrap.sh                 logwrapper                           I  [1m[31m==26800==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x006fad8a2e73 at pc 0x006faf9110e8 bp 0x007fddf81fc0 sp 0x007fddf81fb8
2024-01-30 17:55:53.743 26794-26794 wrap.sh                 logwrapper                           I  [1m[0m[1m[34mREAD of size 1 at 0x006fad8a2e73 thread T0
```

Answer (score 0):

El error de `global-buffer-overflow` que estás recibiendo al analizar la sección .text en memoria con tu código de Android es porque estás accediendo a una dirección de memoria fuera de los límites permitidos para el buffer que estás tratando de leer. Te comparto algunas consideraciones para tu codigo:

- Cálculo Incorrecto del loadBias: El cálculo de loadBias como
  `(uintptr_t)elfheader + current->p_vaddr` podría no estar apuntando
  al inicio correcto del segmento que quieres leer. Revisa si el
  cálculo de la dirección base del segmento esta correcto.
- Desbordamiento del Búfer: El bucle `for` que recorre el segmento
  puede estar intentando leer más allá del final del segmento. Esto
  podría ocurrir si `current->p_memsz` no representa el tamaño real del
  segmento en memoria o si el cálculo de loadBias no es correcto.
- Alineación y Acceso a la Memoria: Estás utilizando `ALIGNMENT` en tu
  bucle `for`, pero no se muestra cómo se define esta constante.
  Asegúrate de que `ALIGNMENT` esté definido de manera que no te lleve
  a leer fuera de los límites del segmento. Además, verifica que cada
  acceso a la memoria `(*(p + 3), *(p + 2), etc.)` esté dentro de los
  límites del segmento.
- Validación de Punteros: Antes de acceder a la memoria con el puntero
  p, deberías validar que p y los punteros derivados (p + 1, p + 2, p +
  3) estén dentro de los límites del segmento.
- AddressSanitizer y Diagnóstico: AddressSanitizer es una excelente
  herramienta para revisar problemas de memoria. Podría ser útil
  reducir el alcance de tu análisis a un segmento o rango de memoria
  más pequeño y ver si aún obtienes errores.

Espero que te ayude, saludos!